# What's the best way to achieve this layout with HTML/CSS; Flexbox, Grid or Other?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, css-tables

[image]

```css
.phone {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.phone > span {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.phone > span.icon {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="phone">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </span>
  <span>Phone</span>
  <span>555-555-5555</span>
</a>
```

Here's what I've tried, but it's not working for me when flex-flow is column. I also am looking for a cross browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

`display` is full of options and not only `flex` or `grid` :

here is another one :

```css
/* basic layout*/

.phone {
  display: table;
  /*or inline-table */
}

.icon {
  display: table-cell;
}

span {
  display: block;
}


/*makeup*/

.phone {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  transition:0.2s;
}

.icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid 1px gray;
}

span {
  padding: 0.5em
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #555;
}

a ~ a .icon {width:25%;
  }
.icon  ~  .icon{border-left:1px solid gray;}

/* demo with hover to test layout behavior */

.phone:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="phone">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </span>
  <span>Phone</span>
  <span>555-555-5555</span>
</a>

<hr>
you can add another spanning cell 
<a class="phone">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </span>
  <span>Phone</span>
  <span>555-555-5555</span>
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. How did you know that table-cell would get moved to the left though? There's nothing in the code that would tell me this is definitely going to be aligned to the left when I set it to table-cell.

Comment: @BlakeBell that is the regular behavior of a table-layout , i actually broke it on purpose sending setting next spans to the nex column but as regular blocks so they pile as normal. they fill up that virtual cell because its meant to be another cell aside not a block element. display:table/table-cell (& family) are n the spec since 1998 with CSS2. ;) you can break into a table too https://jsfiddle.net/q045doef/

Answer (score 1):

Here with css grid my preference.

```css
.phone {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
}

.phone .icon{
  background: aliceblue;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
.phone span{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="phone">
  <span class="icon">
    icon
  </span>
  <span>Phone</span>
  <span>555-555-5555</span>
</a>
```